# API multiple Get methods and routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a controller with only Get Methods

```
public class DeviceController : ApiController
{
    List<Device> machines = new List<Device>();

    public IEnumerable<Device> GetAllMachines()
    {
        //do something
        return machines;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Device> GetMachineByID(int id)
    {
        //do something
        return machines;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Device> GetMachinesByKey(string key)
    {
        //do something
        return machines;
    }
```

}

I would like to be able to access these via URL and get the data back

```
../api/{contorller}/GetAllMachines
../api/{contorller}/GetMachineByID/1001
../api/{contorller}/GetMachiesByKey/HP (machines exist)
```

When i run the first two in IE developer mode (f12) i get Json back displaying all machines and machine 1001. However when i run GetMachinesByKey/HP i get  404 error.

Also my WebApiConfig looks like this

```
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{Action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Anyone enlighten me as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at this article, might help you out. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#enable

Comment: I think the routing engine is expecting to bind to a variable named `id` as defined in the route config; your action parameter is named `key` and so the framework isn't connecting those dots for you.

Comment: @DaveParsons is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routing engine is expecting to bind to a variable named `id` as defined in the route config:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{Action}/{id}", //<--- here {id} means bind to parameter named 'id'
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

In your action `GetMachinesByKey(string key)` parameter is named `key` and so the framework isn't connecting those dots for you.

You could pass the parameter in the querystring so using a URL of the form `/api/{contorller}/GetMachiesByKey/?key=HP` will bind correctly (you may need to change the route config as this doesn't pass an `id` parameter that the current config will be expecting).

Alternatively I believe you can specify a route for an action using [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2). This allows you to decorate your action method with an attribute which tells the framework how the route should be resolved e.g:

```
[Route("<controller>/GetMachinesByKey/{key}")]
public IEnumerable<Device> GetMachinesByKey(string key)
```

Comment: Thankyou for your explanation, i have added the routes in my controller and i am able to access the data

Answer (score 0):

Use the RoutePrefix and Route attributes.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/device")]
public class DeviceController : ApiController
{
List<Device> machines = new List<Device>();

[HttpGet]
[Route("Machines")]
public IEnumerable<Device> GetAllMachines()
{
    //do something
    return machines;
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("Machines/{id:int}")]
public IEnumerable<Device> GetMachineByID(int id)
{
    //do something
    return machines;
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("Machines/{key}")]
public IEnumerable<Device> GetMachinesByKey(string key)
{
    //do something
    return machines;
}
```

Comment: This helped, thankyou - So with these added, my WebApiConfig is not needed or?

Comment: config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes is sufficient.